# How ActiveMQ save message in database field MSG?

Tags: activemq-classic

i tried to get message text from database as needed for some internal statistics, i used TextMessage but i cant get object from MSG field in database.

```
WireFormat wireFormat = new OpenWireFormat();
ActiveMQTextMessage answer = new ActiveMQTextMessage();
String testString = "... BLOB(hex) data from MSG field used for test ...";
byte[] test =  new BigInteger(testString,16).toByteArray();
answer = (ActiveMQTextMessage) wireFormat.unmarshal(new ByteSequence(test));
```

and wireFormat always return null object.
On the server side i used also TextMessages and OpenWireFormat, and when convert BLOB to String i see id queue name and other data but not eye well formated

What to do to get ActiveMQTextMessage from this field?

Comment: Take a look at [DefaultJDBCAdapter.doAddMessage()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.activemq/activemq-jdbc-store/5.10.0/org/apache/activemq/store/jdbc/adapter/DefaultJDBCAdapter.java#DefaultJDBCAdapter); I think it's the class through which the database write is happening, so you should be able to reverse-engineer it to get what you want.

Comment: i see there for marshaling byte array as bytesequence, but i cant get unmarshal data, always return null.

Comment: I'd recommend attaching a debugger to that code while it's doing a write (in a dev/test environment, of course) and stepping through the code to figure out what it's doing.  Once you do that, it should be clear how to do the inverse.  But I don't use JDBC (or any form of persistence) in the brokers I use, so I can't offer any more precise suggestions than that.  Good luck.